# Bash How To Select Multiple Lines from ldif-type File based on dn

Tags: linux, bash, ldap, ldif

I am wondering how best to parse an ldif file (and ldif-like files) so that I can import each DN entry and its associated attributes into variables, without crossing over into other DNs and their attributes, as everything is in a single file.

Please how can this be done?

Thanks for helping a noob out.

Edit:
An example ldif-like file looks something like this:

```
    dn: cn=admins,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=mydom,dc=com
    Group name: admins
    Description: Account administrators group
    GID: 721800000
    Member users: admin, user2, user1
    ipauniqueid: 2dafa3a2-b903-11e2-8a28-525400a60ac3
    objectclass: top, groupofnames, posixgroup, ipausergroup, ipaobject, nestedGroup

    dn: cn=editors,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=mydom,dc=com
    Group name: editors
    Description: Limited admins who can edit other users
    GID: 721800002
    Member users: user1
    ipauniqueid: 2dc4446a-b903-11e2-a2fa-525400a60ac3
    objectclass: top, groupofnames, posixgroup, ipausergroup, ipaobject, nestedGroup

    dn: cn=employees,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=mydom,dc=com
    Group name: employees
    Description: Default group for all Qrios employees
    GID: 721800006
    Member users: user2, user3
    ipauniqueid: 134ae6e0-b910-11e2-a7f3-525400a60ac3
    objectclass: top, groupofnames, nestedgroup, ipausergroup, ipaobject, posixgroup
```

I would like to be able to select sections of the file, based on the first keyword (dn), and import the values of the lines into variables so I can make use of them, and then move to the next section.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be a bit more specific. Update your question with an example input and the expected output as well as what you have tried to do to solve the problem and where it failed and we'd gladly help! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @FredrikPihl . I am still trying to wrap my head around what needs doing, I am really not certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sina, I am working with the LDIF format quite a lot and bash just does not cut it. 
I would strongly advise you to start using perl or python with their respective LDAP modules:

- http://ldap.perl.org/
- http://www.python-ldap.org/

Just a small example of perl with its LDAP module:

```
# Read in the LDIF file specified in $input_file
my $ldif = Net::LDAP::LDIF->new($input_file, "r", onerror => 'warn', change => 1);
#
# Process the LDIF input file
#
while($entry = $ldif->read()) 
{
        # Get the Member attribute
        my @mbr = $entry->get_value('Member');
        foreach my $value (@mbr)
        {
               # Here you have a 'Member' value in $value, do what you want
        }
}
```

As you can see, this makes things quite simple. Also, these modules take into account all the different conventions within LDIF like abbreviated lines, changetypes, and so on.